# WordPress hosted on Azure won't allow media file uploads due to bad temp folder

Tags: wordpress, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-app-service

After recent upgrade to latest WordPress version, media uploads no longer work. They return missing temp folder error.

I found out that WP thinks that /wwwroot/wp-admin/ is the temp folder, that's where it is trying to send uploads.

I tried everything to force it to change within WordPress. Setting WP_TEMP_DIR, even tried rewriting core function that looks for temp folder in /wp-includes/text/Diff.php and setting static path.

Nothing works. I don't really know much about Azure, so it's been a pain in the butt.

My last resort is to install and use Azure Storage plugin for WP, but that's last resort.

Anyone can shed some light on this issue? Would greatly appreciate it.

UPDATE: Site is a Azure website, it does not use Azure instance.
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/web-sites/

Comment: I would try the azure storage plugin. Depending on the size of your Azure vm, you might not have a lot of space for storing uploads. Azure storage is pretty cheap, give it a shot, you might like it.

Comment: Thanks, thats our last option once everything else fails.

Comment: Could you provide some context around which version of wordpress you've installed and the path of the temp folder it can't write to?

Comment: Hey, we've upgraded to the latest version 3.4.2. I was able to display a path of the temp folder to see where it was trying to upload, and for some reason the temp folder WP tries to upload is /wp-admin/
Ex: C:\..\..\..\wp-admin\

I tried everything on WP side to change the path, even re-writing and forcing temp folder location in the core files. Still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not to sure about Azure but you can change the tmp directory WordPress uses by using the command below. Make sure to make a folder in your home directory before doing so.

wp-config

```
define('WP_TEMP_DIR','/link-to-your-folder-you-just-made');
```

Comment: Hey Andy, thanks but I tried that. It keeps pointing to the same location, regardless of wp_temp_dir.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you should never store anything on an Azure instance, consider it volalite storage just like RAM - if the instance goes down or even gets randomly restarted you could literally get a brand new virtual machine with a new file system and lose everything.

That being said, you can safely RDP into the instance - create a directory (c:\temp for example) and as long as the IIS account has rights over the directory you won't have any issues using it as scratch storage. I would use Andy's approach above (I don't know wordpress, but I know Azure) and simply make sure that it points to a directory that you can use as temp and that the IIS user can safely use.

You may want to log in to the VM with RDP if only for the additional reason that it will give you great insight in how Azure structures the file system for the software it runs, you will see 3 drives and if memory serves one of them is purely a scratch drive that you can use. But it's not persistent, consider that it can get cleared at any moment.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for the info Karell. I talked to him, he said he uses Azure websites, not instance.
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/web-sites/

So we have less control.

Comment: These tips don't apply to Windows Azure Web Sites.

Comment: Thanks, but the question didn't specify we were dealing with an azure website instead of an instance.